# Correspondence register in Outlook

Tags: software

I have just taken over a Project Management role and have found that I need to produce a correspondence register from Outlook.

Does anyone know of any add-ons, software or methods which I can use?

Comment: Can you explain further why and what you are trying to accomplish? A correspondence register can be simply a folder in your mailbox, and there are manual and automatic methods to insert mails into those folders.

Comment: Gurkan,  The register is a contractual deliverable.  The register needs to be a table with the following columns DATE, FROM, TO, SUBJECT.

Comment: As written, this appears to be a software recommendation question. It is likely to be closed unless you can provide more context from a project management perspective.

Comment: Please update question with information in comments and remove request for software; software recommendations are out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

### Outlook Journal can be used for  time management and project tracking

Here is a good article on [how to use Outlook Journal for time tracking](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/track-emails-phonecalls-and-tasks-with-outlook-journal/):

- From inside the journal entry, you can also quickly kick off any other Outlook app like an email message, an appointment, a new task and more.  In other words, this actually makes the Journal tool the best project management center for each of the projects you might be working on at your job. What better way to keep track of the overall hours you’ve spent on each project, plus have the ability to tie all of your activities like tasks, email messages and more, directly to the project record?
- Just share out the Journal to your boss, and he or she can quickly monitor your progress and how much time you’re devoting to the project, without the need to keep pestering you about what you’re working on.

And another article [describing other features of Outlook Journal](https://www.itworld.com/article/2714516/consumerization/use-outlook-as-an-automatic-time-tracking-tool.html):

- You can set it to automatically log all task requests, emails, and meeting requests--from specific contacts or all of them.
- If you enable tracking on Office documents, you'll get a log of every time you work on Word, Excel, and/or PowerPoint documents--with the times and names of the docs.

Looks like [Microsoft made it harder to find this feature in Outlook 2013 and 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-is-Journal-cf2a758b-8a9b-494a-a063-36254c428335). In order to find it, here is what you have to do: "On the Navigation Bar, click  Navigation Bar ellipses > Folders > Journal. (Or just press Ctrl+8)."

Comment: Thanks, but it is not time management I am after.  I also have in excess of 10k historic emails I need to be on the register.

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation given in comments, the request is for a simple list of project related emails with the following info

1. From
2. To
3. Subject
4. Date

For this purpose, firstly there must be a way to select which emails are to be reported, and which not.

That can be done in at least two ways:

1. Categories
2. Folder(s)

Categories are useful if you do not want to move emails to a different folder every time, and it can be a matter of select and click. Or it can be automated.

When the emails are designated using category assignment or folder, a VBA macro can be written to get specific fields and write them to a file.

This is how I would do it, if a ready to use add-on is not readily available.

I’d also try to learn How the other project managers in your company/organization deal with this situation.

Here’s a link to VBA related site: [here](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=40)

Comment: Thanks Gurkan, I will have a look.  Unfortunately no other PM maintains any registers, hence my position.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to generate list of who, when, subject line, etc. I would recommend that you start playing the View options in Outlook. There are a lot of ways to approximate a spreadsheet view and then export that list to another format. It's a menu that is easily overlooked.